# detect crashed application with .bat

Tags: batch-file

Hi guys is it possible to detect application crash with .bat code then restart that with .bat.
pleas give me a method.
i write a code to start and restart application but i don't know how to detect crashed application.
thank you

```
@echo off 
cls
echo Protecting NpAPIserver from crashes...
title NpAPIServer Watchdog

tasklist /FI "aplication.exe" | find /i "aplication.exe" 
for /f "tokens=2" %%x in ('tasklist ^| findstr aplication.exe') do set PIDTOKILL=%%x
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 GOTO KILLPROGRAM
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO LAUNCHPROGRAM

:KILLPROGRAM
taskkill /F /PID %PIDTOKILL%
goto LAUNCHPROGRAM

:LAUNCHPROGRAM
cd "c:\np"
start aplication.exe
goto WAITLUNCH

:WAITLUNCH
timeout /T 300
for /f "tokens=2" %%x in ('tasklist ^| findstr aplication.exe') do set PIDTOKILL=%%x
taskkill /F /PID %PIDTOKILL%
goto LAUNCHPROGRAM
```

Comment: does this help? `tasklist /FI "Status eq not responding"`

Comment: Thanks but its find all crashed application but i need just check one application such as lol.exe

Comment: Use the `/im` image filter also

Answer (score -1):

```
(tasklist /FI "Status eq not responding"|find "lol.exe")&&rem not reponding
```